# Proper design of a starring/liking system in Firebase: Should I use transactions?

Tags: android, firebase, transactions, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an app that does something similar to the [star count on a blog post example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) given in the Firebase documentation and I have a question about the design of the polling system and whether to use .

From the example, the data for a post looks like this:

```
postid {
    // some data here about the post, author, id, etc,
    starCount : <an integer count of the stars>,
    stars : {
        <user who starred> : true,
        <user who starred> : true,
        // ... and so on, basically a list of all the users who starred the post
    }
}
```

The docs use a transaction to update the star count:

```
private void onStarClicked(DatabaseReference postRef) {
    postRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            Post p = mutableData.getValue(Post.class);
            if (p == null) {
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            if (p.stars.containsKey(getUid())) {
                // Unstar the post and remove self from stars
                p.starCount = p.starCount - 1;
                p.stars.remove(getUid());
            } else {
                // Star the post and add self to stars
                p.starCount = p.starCount + 1;
                p.stars.put(getUid(), true);
            }

            // Set value and report transaction success
            mutableData.setValue(p);
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                               DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Transaction completed
            Log.d(TAG, "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
        }
    });
}
```

Because of the use of a transaction both the `starCount` and `stars` seem to *need* to be part of the same object. Why? Because I want to use both a transaction and assure automicness. The other option for assuring automicness is multi-path updates, but as noted [here in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40390800/firebase-transactions-on-two-references-possible) you cannot use multi-path updates with transitions. You have access to the `mutableData` (in this case the post object) and that's it.

SO if the `starCount` and `stars` must be stored in the same location, **I don't understand the point of the starCount**. Whenever you get a post object, it will include `stars`, the list of everyone who starred it. Why not remove the starCount entirely and **just get the size of the stars list**? Is there something non performant about this?

In this case,  starring/unstarring something would be something like `p.stars.put(getUid(), true);` and `p.stars.remove(getUid());`. If I did that, I don't see the need for a transaction, because I no longer have multiple users updating a "counter" object. I could use a transaction for the `p.stars.put(getUid(), true);` statement, but it seems highly unlikely to me that the same user who try to star/unstar something from two different devices, and even if they did, it wouldn't be disastrous as far as I can tell.

So what am I missing here? **Why use transactions here and what benefit does storing and manually tracking starCount add?** I could see a performance benefit storing the `stars` user list elsewhere in the database, as shown in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41106637/nesting-stars-in-firebase-database), but then the transaction wouldn't work.

Any insight would be appreciated and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In our effort to create a single working sample app from which to get the documentation samples, we indeed may have created a non-sensible (but functional) use for transactions.

I'd recommend having a look at [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954217/is-the-way-the-firebase-database-quickstart-handles-counts-secure) for a more reasonable (but definitely complex) way of doing secure counts using multi-location updates and server-side security rules.

In general though, I'd always recommend splitting the voting logic from the counting logic in cases like this. So when a user votes for a post, you write a simple record into the database that records their action:

```
votesQueue
   <push id>
      <uid>: true
```

And then you have a tiny server script (e.g. a [firebase queue worker](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue)) that listens to this queue and aggregates the number of votes.

This approach is very common when using Firebase and makes matters a lot simpler. You can probably easily imagine how you'd secure these two nodes (`votesQueue` and `voteTotals`), while I can assure you that the solution in the answer I linked above gives me quite some maintenance headaches.